# There exist $n$ different integers in the interval $\big(k^n,(k+1)^n\big)$ whose product is a perfect $n$-th power.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, analytic-number-theory, perfect-powers

> Given a positive integer $ n> 2 $. Prove that there exists a natural number $ K $ such that for all integers $ k \ge K $ on the open interval $ \big({{k} ^{n}}, \ {{(k + 1)} ^{n}}\big) $ there are $n$ different integers, the product of which is the $n$-th power of an integer.

**Source**  Ukrainian TST 2011

---

**Progress**: Maybe one can choose the smallest prime divisor $q$ of $n$ and then one can choose all $\frac{n}{q}$ powers and among these powers, one can choose $n$ integers whose product is a $q$-th power
In this way, we would just have to prove that 
Between $k^q$ and $(k+1)^q$ we have $n$ integers with their product being a $q$-th power.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this problem? If so, you should put them in the body of your question so that we can be more helpful in answering.

Comment: Sorry but I already tried a lot of analytical stuff but I couldn't proceed.

Comment: Can you please explain the analytical stuff that you tried?

Comment: Can something be done from my progress?

Comment: Even the cool questions need some "context" because we don't want to have separate rules for contest questions. [Our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: The first thing I would try is $n=3$ and some small $K$, say $10$.  Of course, it could be that the appropriate $K$ is huge, but let's try.  Can we find $3$ numbers between $1000$ and $1331$ that multiply to form a cube?  This would work if we could find numbers $p,q,r$ such that $p^2q,q^2r,$ and $r^2p$ are in range.  Unfortunately, neither $10,11,12$ nor $9,11,12$ work.  Can we fix that for larger $K$?

Comment: I don't think it would be easier to visualise in this way as for some $n$ the statement might be true for some very large $K$ which we can't check ourselves

Comment: It leads me to the thought that we need to find a pattern like this where the numbers are close together.  The problem is that (if $p \lt q \lt r), r^2p$ is too much larger than $p^2q$.  Maybe if we choose six numbers about $\sqrt k$ we can have compensating errors that keep the numbers close together.

Comment: We can't count on $n$ not being prime, so there may not be such a $q$  I think we need to find $n$ numbers with a proper structure of factors to multiply to an $n^{th}$ power and chosen to be very close together.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  my efforts to find a combination like I suggested did not succeed either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the intuition that the intervals between consecutive $n$th powers contain many $(n-1)th$ powers, we have the following:

If $n+1$ is odd, for the interval in $(k^{n+1},(k+1)^{n+1})$, we can take the following $n+1$ numbers:
$x_1=a^n,x_2=a^{n-1}(a+1),\ldots,x_n=a(a+1)^{n-1},x_{n+1}=(a+1)^n$,
where $a=\lceil k^{\frac{n+1}{n}} \rceil$.
Clearly $a^n$ falls into the interval, and what needs to be checked is that $(a+1)^n<(k+1)^{n+1}$, and we know that $a+1 < k^{\frac{n+1}{n}}+2$. We can see from binomial expansion that for fixed $n$, the first terms cancel and the leading term has degree $n$ on the RHS and degree $\dfrac{n^2-1}{n}<n$ on the LHS, so for sufficiently large $k$, all these numbers fall into the interval.

Comment: I actually think the method is fine. You simply need a different estimate. Well done +1

Comment: Thanks, that is corrected now.

Comment: Perhaps some modification will work for even $n$ as well, which is still pending.

Comment: If $n=2\ell$, $\ell$ odd, may be you can similarly squeeze in a sequence of the form
$$a^{2(\ell-1)},a^{2(\ell-2)}(a+1)^2,a^{2(\ell-3)}(a+1)^4,\ldots,(a+1)^{2(\ell-1)}?$$ Even if that works (recursively), we would still (only?) be left with the case when $n$ is a power of two.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so finally I think this is the solution $   $

I will just be showing for even $n$

First let $a=\lceil k^{\frac{n}{n-1}} \rceil$
now let $b=a+1$ and $c=a+2$
So setting $x_{i}=a^{n-i}b^{i-1}$ and $y_{i}=c^{n-i}b^{i-1}$ for $i\in [0,n-1]$

We get  $k^n<x_{1}<\cdots x_{n-1}<y_{n-1}<\cdots y_{1}<( k^{\frac{n}{n-1}}+3)^{n-1}$ for all $k\geq 3^{n-1}$
Also note that $( k^{\frac{n}{n-1}}+3)^{n-1}<(k+1)^{n}$ for all $k\geq 3^{n-1}$
From here we just have to make cases and choose $n$ numbers out of these $2n-2$ numbers.

For example for the case $n=4m$ the sequence $(x_{1},x_{3},\cdots, x_{4m-1},y_{1},y_{3},\cdots y_{4m-1})$ works.